# Going to next image and previous image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)next {
          // <-- here
        index++;
        // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
        int imageCount=3;
        if (index<=imageCount) {
            NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i.jpg", index];
            [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
        }
    }
    - (IBAction)prev {
          // <-- here
        index--;
        // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
        int imageCount=3;
        if (index > 1) {
            NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i.jpg", index];
            [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
        }
    }
```

The first one is linked to a button and works fine and changes the image forward. The second one is linked to another button, but will only go backwards one image. I am really stuck and I am in need of severe help. Please could someone help me. (index is a property and sythesized) ImageCount is not. There is also no list of images.
The images are:
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image names are 1-based (there's only img1.jpg, img2.jpg and img3.jpg), perhaps your -prev action should check `if (index >= 1)`?

There are much easier ways of doing this if you only ever have the same three images, however. Maybe you should explain your overall goal (from a very high level - what you want your app to do) and the community can help you choose a better path.